# how to add a new column using a logic statement

Tags: r

I want to create a new column named "another language" that gives me a 0/1 value. The logic I wish to achieve is that 0 if Q1Q4_1, Q1Q4_2, Q1Q4_3, OR Q1Q4_4 = N/A; 1 if Q1Q4_1, Q1Q4_2, Q1Q4_3, OR Q1Q4_4 contains characters other than "English" where Q1Q4_1, Q1Q4_2, Q1Q4_3, OR Q1Q4_4 are other columns in the dataset.

```
full_quiz = read.csv("Project Data/Full_Quiz_Dataset.csv")    
full_quiz$another_language = c(full_quiz$Q1Q4_1,full_quiz$Q1Q4_2, full_quiz$Q1Q4_3,full_quiz$Q1Q4_4) != NA
```

I know this isn't right, but I need some help!

Comment: Hi Linjin. Please don't post images of your data. It's very helpful if you can provide reproducible data, so you could post the output of, for example, `dput(head(df, 20))` where `df` is your data frame. This provides other people with the first 20 rows of your data, so that they can more easily address your question.

Comment: you typically use `!is.na()` rather than `!= NA `, but I echo what @heds1 has said, it would be really helpful if you edited your question with the output of `dput(head(full_quiz))`

Comment: Can you also clarify your logic; what happens in the case where there is a `NA` in the row, but also characters other than `English`? Is that `0` or `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that should be generalizable to your data. It at least gives you an idea of the logic syntax. I've created a simple dataframe that hopefully covers all situations here (for example, English-only; English and another language; languages other than English; NAs; etc.):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(col1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = 
c("English", 
"Japanese", "Mandarin", "N/A"), class = "factor"), col2 = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), .Label = c("Japanese", "Latin", "N/A", "Taiwanese"
), class = "factor"), col3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 
NA), .Label = c("Japanese", "N/A"), class = "factor"), col4 = structure(c(2L, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("N/A", "Polish"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


      col1      col2     col3   col4
1 Mandarin Taiwanese Japanese Polish
2      N/A       N/A      N/A   <NA>
3 Mandarin  Japanese      N/A   <NA>
4  English     Latin     <NA>    N/A
5 Japanese      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
6  English      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
```

In your original picture of your data that you removed, you had some `N/A` values that were strings (rather than `NA`). First thing is to convert them all into true `NA` values:

```
df[df=="N/A"] <- NA
df[df=="n/a"] <- NA
df[df=="NA"] <- NA
df[df=="na"] <- NA
```

Then we can use `mutate` with an `ifelse` statement:

```
df %>% mutate(another_language = ifelse((df$col1 != "English" & !is.na(df$col1))
| (df$col2 != "English" & !is.na(df$col2)) 
| (df$col3 != "English" & !is.na(df$col3)) 
| (df$col4 != "English" & !is.na(df$col4)),
1,
0))
```

`|` is the element-wise logical `OR` operator and `&` is the corresponding `AND` operator. If the condition is met, `df$another_language` is filled with `1`, and `0` if the condition is not met. The logic should be readable. Here's the output:

```
      col1      col2     col3   col4 another_language
1 Mandarin Taiwanese Japanese Polish                1
2     <NA>      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>                0
3 Mandarin  Japanese     <NA>   <NA>                1
4  English     Latin     <NA>   <NA>                1
5 Japanese      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>                1
6  English      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>                0
```